# How to connect styles from the npm library to a project where css-modules are used?

Tags: reactjs

For the project I use the React-Quill package https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill, it is indicated that you can import `import 'react-quill / dist / quill.snow.css' styles.`
Such import into the project component does not include styles, since the project uses css-modules. How to import styles in this case?

webpack config

```js
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
 {
  loader: 'style-loader'
 },
 {
  loader: 'css-loader',
  options: {
    module: true,
    importLoaders: 1,
    localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]'
  }
 },
 {
  loader: 'postcss-loader'
 }
]
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`resourceQuery`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-resourcequery) so you are able to load regular global CSS as well as CSS modules.

**Example**

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.css$/,
        oneOf: [
          {
            // import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css?global'
            resourceQuery: /global/, 
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
          },
          {
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```